# Create an Alias from the Recipe in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I want to create the following Alias from the recipe.

[image: alias]

How is this achieved?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What recipe? I don't think there is a recipe step that can do this, and aliases are not content items, and as such are not inherently importable. You'll probably have to write your own command or recipe step.

Comment: What I really want to achieve is have the default page point to a particular controller and action in a custom module as opposed to a regular page.

Comment: @carrier I'm trying to do the same.  Did you figure out a way or write a command or recipe step to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have created this class to add a command for Orchard to create a new alias from command line or recipe:

```
using Orchard;
using Orchard.Alias;
using Orchard.Commands;
using System;
using Orchard.Environment;
using System.Linq;

namespace Contrib.Foundation.Common.Commands
{
    public class AliasCommands : DefaultOrchardCommandHandler
    {
        private readonly Work<WorkContext> _workContext;
        private readonly IAliasService _aliasService;

        public AliasCommands(Work<WorkContext> workContext, IAliasService aliasService,
            IOrchardServices orchardServices)
        {
            _workContext = workContext;
            _aliasService = aliasService;
            Services = orchardServices;
        }
        public IOrchardServices Services { get; private set; }

        [OrchardSwitch]
        public string AliasPath { get; set; }
        [OrchardSwitch]
        public string RoutePath { get; set; }

        [CommandName("alias add")]
        [CommandHelp("alias add /AliasPath:<alias-path> /RoutePath:<route-path>\r\n\t" + "Add a new alias")]
        [OrchardSwitches("AliasPath,RoutePath")]
        public void Add()
        {
            AliasPath = AliasPath.TrimStart('/', '\\');
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AliasPath))
            {
                AliasPath = "/";
            }
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(RoutePath))
            {
                Context.Output.WriteLine(T("Route can't be empty"));
                return;
            }       
            if (CheckAndWarnIfAliasExists(AliasPath))
            {
                Context.Output.WriteLine(T("Alias already exist"));
                return;
            }
            try
            {
                _aliasService.Set(AliasPath, RoutePath, "Custom");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Services.TransactionManager.Cancel();
                Context.Output.WriteLine(T("An error occured while creating the alias {0}: {1}. Please check the values are correct.", AliasPath, ex.Message));
                return;
            }
            Context.Output.WriteLine(T("Alias {0} created.", AliasPath));
        }
        private string GetExistingPathForAlias(string aliasPath)
        {
            var routeValues = _aliasService.Get(aliasPath.TrimStart('/', '\\'));
            if (routeValues == null) return null;

            return _aliasService.LookupVirtualPaths(routeValues, _workContext.Value.HttpContext)
                .Select(vpd => vpd.VirtualPath)
                .FirstOrDefault();
        }
        private bool CheckAndWarnIfAliasExists(string aliasPath)
        {
            var routePath = GetExistingPathForAlias(aliasPath);
            if (routePath == null) return false;

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

You can use it in a recipe like this:

```
<Command>
alias add /AliasPath:"/" /RoutePath:"mycontroller"
</Command>
```

Put the class inside your module and reference Orchard.Alias