# Orchard AliasUI in a Recipe

Tags: orchardcms

I am using the AliasUI module in Orchard to configure a custom homepage from one of my modules.  I set the "/" alias to a route in one of my custom modules.  Is there a way to export this configuration into a custom recipe so it will be automatically configured once the recipe is run?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Orchard.Setup`; The commands and the recipes, There are commands all over the source; In the Blog module, for example. 

If your code works now, it shouldn't matter where you run it from.

Comment: I don't see a command to create an alias in either Orchard.Setup or Orchard.Alias.

Comment: An Alias for a ContentType will be driven by the AutoRoute Part. hooking up to its Service should help you. Check out other ContentTypes, Pages, Blogs. You can see of its done in their Import commands. 
Having said that, check AutoRoute Service, Driver and Handler. in the handler you can see how the Aliases are regenerated. 
Perhaps a little investigation on your side could be if the Autoroute Handler Event fires when a contentype is created from a Recipe. I think it does, but never assume, right?.

Comment: this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17285866/create-an-alias-from-the-recipe-in-orchard